# can CSS 'content' property grab the value of inline style?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
<div style="background-image: url(http://some_url.com);"></div>

div:after {
    content: attr(style[background-image]);
}
```

Goal here being I want to grab a value for content from something that is applied inline to an html element. Is this possible, and if so what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attr()` is for HTML attributes only, not CSS properties. Even if you could obtain `attr(style)` (which you actually *can*), you'll only obtain the text value of that attribute, which is the following string:

```
"background-image: url(http://some_url.com);"
```

However, you won't be able to do anything meaningful with this text value (except printing it as `content` maybe).

If you want your pseudo-element to have the same background image as your element, use:

```
div:after {
    background-image: inherit;
}
```

Again, this by itself is not very meaningful; you have to specify other styles like the rest of the `background` property values, as well as giving it dimensions.

If you want to grab the URL of the background image and print it as content, that's not doable with CSS. You'll need to use JavaScript to look at the computed `background-image` value, parse that value, and insert it as content, instead of using an `:after` pseudo-element.

Comment: OK thanks, but I guess what I'm really asking then is it possible to grab just one style from the html attribute if multiple styles are applied. regardless of what u can do with that value. can i do something like attr(style[background-image])

Comment: As stated in my first sentence, `attr()` cannot be used for CSS properties, so it's not possible.